# Iterating through custom map && handling several streams

Tags: c++, iterator, ofstream, ostream

I'm new to C++ and not 100% sure how I can iterate over maps. 
For the project, I need to have a map that stores key: [name of file / stream] and value: [logger::severity]. Among the filenames there might be an object of ostream cout.

I came up to pretty much nothing:

```
enum class severity
    {
        trace,
        debug,
        information,
        warning,
        error,
        critical
    };

std::map<std::ofstream, severity> this_loggers_streams;

for (std::map<std::ofstream, severity>::iterator iter = this_loggers_streams.begin(); 
          iter != this_loggers_streams.end(); ++iter) {
      iter->first << "" << std::endl;      
      }
}
```

My IDE warns me that there is a no viable conversion for my iterator and Invalid operands to binary expression (`const std::basic_ofstream<char>` and `const char[1]`).

How can I iterate over my map? What will be the best solution to have an ability to write in file and in `std::cout` as it can be a member of my map?

Comment: its very odd to have a map with a stream as a key. Seems like you just want a container of stream, severity pairs

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are trying to use a map? What specific feature of `std::map` are you intending to use? If you only want to iterate over pairs of streams and severity, wouldn't a `std::vector` of `std::pair<std::ofstream, severity>` make more sense?

Comment: [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) suspected. If you take a step back from the technicalities, what are you trying to accomplish? What effect on the world should your iteration have?

Comment: Implementing `operator<` for a `std::ofstream` is going to be a nifty trick.

Comment: Actually, I need ofstreams to have an abilty to output strings in then=m for logger. Maybe it would be better to have strings -- filenames as key and pair<ofstream, severity>?

Comment: Yes, that would be the way to go. `std::ofstream` objects anyway don't store the filenames. You can use `std::pair` or perhaps create your own ofstream class by inheriting from `std::ofstream` and attach the severity enum as a class member.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Keys in a map are const values. That code is invalid and can't be fixed without changing the software design:

```
iter->first << "" << std::endl;  // iter->first is const std::ofstream
```

A possible change:

```
std::list<std::pair<std::ofstream, severity>> this_loggers_streams;
```

Comment: Actually I don't need to change the key of map, but I wanted to use ofstream to have an ability to write in them in my function. And I don't now how to handle cout in them as it's not ostream.

Comment: @Svetlana Don't you understand that you can't output into a const ofstream? There is no way to use a map with ofstream in keys. You **need**, even you **have** to change the key of the map.

Comment: Ok, I understood you, thanks a lot! The structure like 'std::map<std::string, std::pair<std::ofstream, severity>> this_loggers_streams;' might be the key to success?

Comment: @Svetlana I don't know why you need string keys.

Answer (score -2):

STL containers, including `std::map`, can be iterated through iterators in the same way.

For example:

```cpp
for(auto it{x.begin()}; it != x.end(); ++it){
  // something
}
```

However, `std::ofstream` should not be used as `key_type`, since keys are constants, and therefore can not be used when a non-const context is required.